# Ugly separator line in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I experience this problem on both samsung i5500 and i5800:
[image]

Looks like height of divider is between 0 and 1 pixels, so it sometimes rounds to 0 and sometimes to 1. The picture changes if i scroll it.
And if i increase dividerHeight (i tried 2px and 2pt), then it becomes exactly 1 pixel thicker: from 0px it becomes 1px and from 1px it becomes 2px, looking like a kind of wave.

Comment: What's your question? And what's your layout look like? Are you using a custom theme? Do other apps look like that?

Comment: I'd like separator line to be 1px height. or 2 px height.

Comment: I do not know how to use custom theme, so i think i'm using default theme.
Some (but not each) other applications (usual apps from market and samples from android sdk) experience this problem, too.

Answer (score 3):

try setting android:anyDensity = "true", hab similar problems when not set / set to "false"

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens = "true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" 
     />
```

Comment: wow. i almost gave up with the problem. i'll try your solution in a few hours. thank you.