# Ugly preference screen on Samsung I5800

Tags: android, listview, preferences, preferencescreen

I created a simple preferense screen. In emulator, it works well, but in my phone...
Strange shadows below activity's title, thin lines flick when I scroll (images 2-3), and a strange bottom border of "Speed" ListPreference. All other apps' preferences sroll smooth and work well. So what I did wrong? Maybe some problems with dencity?

P.S.: I installed Google's ApiDemos - ListView looks bad too.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quessed right: it's a problem with density. Looks like it exists only on Samsung i5800 and i5500. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434574/ugly-separator-line-in-listview/5700638#5700638) answer helped me.